# CSS same style for a:link a:visited a:hover a:active, really have to write it all out 4 times

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ho ho,

When working with CSS. If the CSS style is the same for a:link a:visited a:hover a:active does one really have to write it out for times. Working with a custom link.

```
.DT_compare a:link {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#EEE;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Any shortcuts?

Marvellous

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just forget the pseudo-classes, and select only `a`:

```
.DT_compare a {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#EEE;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This isn't a very specific selector though; if necessary you can find some other way to increase it so it overrules your `a:hover` and `a:active` selectors, or go with [whoughton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567948/css-same-style-for-alink-avisited-ahover-aactive-really-have-to-write-it-all/5567984#5567984) instead and just specify all four of them.

Then again, if your main hyperlink styles apply to `a:hover` and `a:active` without anything before them, as long as you place your `.DT_compare a` rule beneath them it should work fine.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think you can do any shorter than:

```
.DT_compare a:link,
.DT_compare a:visited,
.DT_compare a:hover,
.DT_compare a:active, {
  font-family:"Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:14px;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
  color:#EEE;
  text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have some styling that you want to override the default browser styles here and that's why I recommend still explicitly stating them. If you do not, then do as the others recommend.

Comment: @Marthin: Specificity may be an issue for `a:hover` and `a:active`. See his comment.

Answer (score 2):

just leave the `:link` off to affect all the states at once.

Answer (score 0):

[Less](http://lesscss.org/) can help here via 'mixins', e.g.:

```
.a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:link { .a; }
a:visited { .a; }
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there were a nicer way but that's the best I know. **less** is seriously great - it's basically CSS, but how a programmer would have designed it. You'll never have to repeat yourself again...

Answer (score 0):

```
.DT_compare a[href]{ ... }
```

is nice because you can sneak in some extra specificity there. (attribute selector == class selector, though).

Answer (score -2):

```
.DT_compare a:link, a:visited {
font-family:"Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:14px;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
color:#EEE;
text-align:center;
}

.DT_compare a:hover, a:active {
font-family:"Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
line-height:14px;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
color:#EEE;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Answered already. wow. Can't just type an answer it has to be indented 4 spaces and just wow

Comment: As to why this answer is wrong: comma has the least precedence; to mean what the poster wanted it to mean, the selectors should be `.DT_compare a:link, .DT_compare a:visited` (and so on) instead. There’s also nothing limiting the comma to _two_ selectors, you can just as well specify all four.