# Is it possible to make this link styling css shorter?

Tags: css

I have the following code which styles links:

```
.language_nav a:link, .language_nav a:visited, .language_nav a:hover,.language_nav a:active {
    color: seagreen;
}
```

Is it possible to make this shorter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest answer is

```
.language_nav a {color: seagreen;}
```

and in all condition a color will be seagrenn.

Refference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567948/css-same-style-for-alink-avisited-ahover-aactive-really-have-to-write-it-al)

Answer (score 3):

**Without** a preprocessor like `SASS` or `LESS`

```
.language_nav a:link,
.language_nav a:visited,
.language_nav a:hover,
.language_nav a:active {
    color: seagreen;
}
```

**With** a preprocessor like `SASS` or `LESS`

```
.language_nav a {
  &:link,
  &:visited,
  &:hover,
  &:active {
    color: seagreen;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Leothelion My answer was actually made in consideration of some future changes. Like if the OP would like to add an hover effect, active... etc or just have a look on preprocessors. Both answers are actually true and useful for the OP I think.

Comment: the op already asked for hover and active and your code first snippet is as same as op's. Please check. I don't have any issue with you but just sharing with you so you will notice and edit. All we want user solution, thats it so please read back.

Comment: @Leothelion That's what I try to explain, your post is the direct answer to the question `Is it possible to make this shorter?` that's also why yours should be the accepted answer. Otherwise my answer is an invitation to go beyond, and is - for a syntax purpose - the most correct considering that all those anchors (+ `:focus`) should always be defined even if no-one do that anymore. So yes, both answers are correct.

Comment: Please, m not saying your answer is wrong and i never said..but m just saying that your first code is as same as op and second one is little bit confused.Please read the op's question then you will realize and there is no explanation in my answer it will apply to a in all condition that's why..sorry if my words hurt..

Comment: @Leothelion I think you really don't get my point. Nevermind.